# How do you get the DataKeyField from a Linkbutton inside a Datalist?

Tags: asp.net

New to asp.net so any help would be great Thank you.

I have a Datalist with has product name, price, Image and a linkbutton inside a datalist it also holds ProductID which is not displayed.

How do you get the current productID from onClick event of the LinkButton thank you.

My DataList

```
<asp:DataList ID="dlProduct" runat="server" DataKeyField="ProductID" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatColumns="4" CellPadding="10" CellSpacing="10" >
                    <ItemTemplate>                                 
                        <asp:Label ID="ProductNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProductName") %>' />   
                        <br />Price:
                        <asp:Label ID="PriceLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# "$" + Eval("Price") %>'  />
                        <br />            
                        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" CssClass="ImageStyles" ImageUrl='<%# "GetImage.ashx?Id=" + Eval("PID") %>' BackColor="White" BorderStyle="Ridge" BorderColor="WhiteSmoke" />
                        <br />
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="btnAddToCart" OnClick="btnAddToCart_Click" runat="server"><img src="images/AddToCart.png" onmouseover="this.src='images/AddToCartMouseOver.png';" onmouseout="this.src='images/AddToCart.png';" /></asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:DataList>
```

My Code behind

```
protected void btnAddToCart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "temp", "<script language='javascript'>alert('Product ID = "+ PID.Text + "');</script>", false);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the CommandArgument property of the LinkButton control.

Like:

```
            <asp:LinkButton ID="btnAddToCart"
                CommandName="AddToCart" 
                CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ProductId") %>' 
                 OnCommand="btnAddToCart_Command" runat="server">
```

Then in the `btnAddToCart_Command` you can get command argument like this.

```
    protected void btnAddToCart_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs args)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "temp", "<script language='javascript'>alert('Product ID = " + args.CommandArgument+ "');</script>", false);
    }
```

Hope this helps.